# I am unable to open corrupt MS Excel file due

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to repair and recover corrupt MS excel file? I am unable to open corrupt MS Excel file due to virus infected, I have crucial Workbook sheet got lost, so how to get back corrupted MS Excel file. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using an archiver application such as 7-Zip you can expand the .xlsx (a .zip) where you will find a number of folders. For Excel files there should be a folder banned "xl" with a child folder named "worksheets" that contain XML files of your worksheets. You can then try to rebuild your worksheets...

Remember: always backup your most important files!